# Measure space of cartesian product

Tags: measure-theory, tensor-products

If $X$ and $Y$ are two locally compact Hausdorff spaces, we have their associated measure spaces $M(X)$ and $M(Y)$.

Is $M(X\times Y)$ describably in terms of the two smaller spaces?

My guess is $M(X)\hat{\otimes} M(Y)$ (projective tensor product), via the map

$$\mu\otimes \nu\mapsto \mu \times \nu\text{, for all }\mu\in M(X),\nu\in M(Y)$$

which is well defined by the universal property of the tensor product.

I haven't managed to check all the details, however and I thought it would be much more efficient to ask.

Comment: What is your operation $X \mapsto M(X)$ that associates a measure space with a locally compact Hausdorff space?

Comment: If you're asking me for the definition of $M(X)$, its the space of all complex regular Borel measures on $X$, normed by total variation.

If you're asking about how to map $X$ into $M(X)$, there is an injective map $X\mapsto M(X)$ sending each $x\in X$ to the corresponding point mass measure $\delta_{x}$.

Comment: The $M(X\times Y)$ will have all the product measures, whereas $\mu\times \nu$ only gives you independent products. At least one ugly way to do things is to use $\xi$ that sends a space of measures $M$ to its subspace of measures that only take $\{0,1\}$ values. In that case, if you have $P = M(X)$ and $Q = M(Y)$ it seems that you can do $M(\xi(P)\times \xi(Q))$. Is that fine in terms of describability?

Comment: From your explanation it seems that we can do no better, thanks!